# Alternative way of implementing nested if statement

Tags: java, list, object, if-statement

I am trying to refactor this code I have below that uses several nested if statements to check if two list contains the same items.

```
List<Car> CarList = CarService.findCarByConfigtype(pageName);
for (int i = 0; i < CarList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(CarRestApiController.data().getModel());
    if (CarList.get(i).getModel().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getModel())) {
        dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getModel());
        if (CarList.get(i).getDerivative().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getDerivative())) {
            dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getDerivative());
            if (CarList.get(i).getSvp().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getSvp())) {
                dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getSvp());
                if (CarList.get(i).getEngine().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getEngine())) {
                    dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getEngine());
                    if (CarList.get(i).getFueltype().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getFueltype())) {
                        dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getFueltype());
                        if (CarList.get(i).getBodystyle().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getBodystyle())) {
                            dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getBodystyle());
                            if (CarList.get(i).getTransmission().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getTransmission())) {
                                dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getTransmission());
                                if (CarList.get(i).getSalescategory().equals(CarRestApiController.data().getSalescategory())) {
                                    dataFound.add(CarList.get(i).getSalescategory());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is save the result of `CarList.get(i)` and `CarRestApiController.data()` to variables rather than repeating them over and over again. (If they're simple getters, this is mostly to make it easier to read. If they're complex getters, it's to make it easier to read and quicker to execute.) For the rest of it, I'd lean toward seeing if I could change the overall object structure.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do here?

Comment: @ernest_k Car class has the getter and setter for model, derivative, svp, engine, fueltype, bodystyle and transmission. I am adding those data to a list to check what the user submitted from the frontend vs what data was saved in the database.

Comment: @marstran I am trying to do a test where it checks the database and narrows down the result depending on the selection of inputs from the frontend. So that I can do assertEquals to find if a list of inputs from the frontend equals a list of data found in the database.

Comment: But you are only interested in the "getDerivative" if "getModel" was added to the list, and only interested in "getSvp" if both "getModel" and "getDerivative" was added to the list, and so on?

Comment: @marstran yeah thats what i wanted to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first save the result of `CarList.get(i)` and `CarRestApiController.data()` to variables as @T.J.Crowder suggested. Then I would flip the if-checks and use `continue` to get rid of the nesting. Like this:

```
List<Car> carList = CarService.findCarByConfigtype(pageName);

for (int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {
     Car apiData = CarRestApiController.data();
     Car carListData = carList.get(i);

     System.out.println(CarRestApiController.data().getModel());

     if (!carListData.getModel().equals(apiData.getModel())) {
         continue;
     }
     dataFound.add(carListData.getModel());

     if (!carListData.getDerivative().equals(apiData.getDerivative())) {
         continue;
     }
     dataFound.add(carListData.getDerivative());

     if (!carListData.getSvp().equals(apiData.getSvp())) {
         continue;
     }
     dataFound.add(carListData.getSvp());

     // ... and so on.
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to use [Strategy design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy). Have a strategy for each if statement, iterate over the list of strategies and process each car in the list

```
public interface CarFeatureStrategy {

    boolean canProcess(Car carToProcess, Car carToMatch);

    Object process(Car carToProcess);
}
```

The `canHandle` method should encapsulate the if statements which needs to be true to allow the processing and the `process` method should return the value of corresponding property of the car (for the example in the description there should be 8 strategies)

```
public class ModelStrategy implements CarFeatureStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean canProcess(Car carToProcess, Car carToMatch) {
        return carToProcess.getModel().equals(carToMatch.getModel));
    }

    @Override
    public Object process(Car carToProcess) {
        return carToProcess.getModel();
    }
}

public class DerivativeStrategy implements CarFeatureStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean canProcess(Car carToProcess, Car carToMatch) {
        return carToProcess.getModel().equals(carToMatch.getModel())
                && carToProcess.getDerivative().equals(carToMatch.getDerivative());
    }

    @Override
    public Object process(Car carToProcess) {
        return carToProcess.getDerivative();
    }
}

public class SvpStrategy implements CarFeatureStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean canProcess(Car carToProcess, Car carToMatch) {
        return carToProcess.getModel().equals(carToMatch.getModel())
                && carToProcess.getDerivative().equals(carToMatch.getDerivative())
                && carToProcess.getSvp().equals(carToMatch.getSvp());
    }

    @Override
    public Object process(Car carToProcess) {
        return carToProcess.getSvp();
    }
}

// .... and so on for each condition which needs to be met
// EngineStrategy, FueltypeStrategy, BodystyleStrategy,
// TransmissionStrategy, SalescategoryStrategy
```

The `CarProcessor` retrieves the cars corresponding to the given `pageName`, retrieves the data from the `CarRestApiController` and uses the list of strategies to process the cars

```
public class CarProcessor {


    private CarService carService;
    private CarRestApiController restController;

    private List<CarFeatureStrategy> carFeatureStrategies;

    public void processCars(Object pageName) {
        // for example purpose the list of strategies is initialized here,
        // but it should be initialized somwhere where the initialization is done
        // only once rather than each time the processCars method is called
        carFeatureStrategies = new ArrayList<>();
        carFeatureStrategies.add(new ModelStrategy());
        carFeatureStrategies.add(new DerivativeStrategy());
        carFeatureStrategies.add(new SvpStrategy());
        // ....
        // add to the strategies list an instance of each strategy to process 
        // the car

        Car carToMatch = restController.data();
        List<Car> cars = carService.findCarByConfigtype(pageName);
        List<Object> dataFound = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Car carToProcess : cars) {
            for (CarFeatureStrategy carFeatureStrategy : carFeatureStrategies) {
                if (carFeatureStrategy.canProcess(carToProcess, carToMatch)) {
                    dataFound.add(carFeatureStrategy.process(carToProcess));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example could be optimised implementing the [Chain of responsibility design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility/java/example). With a chain of responsibility the if statements in the `canHandle` methods will simplify to only one boolean condition per strategy.

For chain of responsibility the strategies have to be enhanced with a method to return the next strategy in the chain

```
public interface CarFeatureStrategy {

    boolean canProcess(Car carToProcess, Car carToMatch);

    Object process(Car carToProcess);

    CarFeatureStrategy next();
}
```

the strategy implementations have to be enhanced with a reference to the next strategy in the chain

```
public class ModelStrategy implements CarFeatureStrategy {

    private CarFeatureStrategy nextStrategy;

    public ModelStrategy(CarFeatureStrategy nextStrategy) {
        this.nextStrategy = nextStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canProcess(Car carToProcess, Car carToMatch) {
        // check only the model
        return carToProcess.getModel().equals(carToMatch.getModel));
    }

    @Override
    public Object process(Car carToProcess) {
        return carToProcess.getModel();
    }

    @Override
    public CarFeatureStrategy next() {
        return this.nextStrategy;
    }
}

public class DerivativeStrategy implements CarFeatureStrategy {

    private CarFeatureStrategy nextStrategy;

    public DerivativeStrategy(CarFeatureStrategy nextStrategy) {
        this.nextStrategy = nextStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canProcess(Car carToProcess, Car carToMatch) {
        // check only the derivative property
        return carToProcess.getDerivative().equals(carToMatch.getDerivative());
    }

    @Override
    public Object process(Car carToProcess) {
        return carToProcess.getDerivative();
    }

    @Override
    public CarFeatureStrategy next() {
        return this.nextStrategy;
    }
}

// ... and so on for all the strategies
```

The `CarProcessor` should build a chain of strategies and process each car until the chain is finished (the `next` method of current strategy returns null) or the current strategy cannot process the current car (`canHandle` method of current strategy returns false)

```
public class CarProcessor {

    private CarService carService;
    private CarRestApiController restController;

    public void processCars(Object pageName) {
        // for example purpose the chain of responsibilities is initialized here,
        // but it should be initialized somwhere where the initialization is done
        // only once rather than each time the processCars method is called

        // initialise the chain of responsibilities in revers order
        CarFeatureStrategy salesCategoryStrategy = new SalescategoryStrategy(null);
        CarFeatureStrategy transmissionStrategy = new TransmissionStrategy(salesCategoryStrategy);
        CarFeatureStrategy bodystyleStrategy = new BodystyleStrategy(transmissionStrategy);
        CarFeatureStrategy fueltypeStrategy = new FueltypeStrategy(bodystyleStrategy);
        CarFeatureStrategy engineStrategy = new EngineStrategy(fueltypeStrategy);
        // .... and so on until the first strategy in the chain
        CarFeatureStrategy modelStrategy = new ModelStrategy(...);

        Car carToMatch = restController.data();
        List<Car> cars = carService.findCarByConfigtype(pageName);
        List<Object> dataFound = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Car carToProcess : cars) {
            CarFeatureStrategy currentStrategy = modelStrategy;
            do {
                if ( !currentStrategy.canProcess(carToProcess, carToMatch)) {
                    // if current strategy cannot process the current car
                    // stop the chain
                    break;
                }

                dataFound.add(currentStrategy.process(carToProcess));
                // move to the next strategy in the chain
                currentStrategy = currentStrategy.next();

            } while (currentStrategy != null)
        }
    }
}
```